# Getting rid of special characters and unicode in byte object converted to string in Python

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I'm having difficulty getting ride of special characters and unicode in Pandas dataframe.

Here is an example of one of the byte objects:

```
b"Asana Check out your two-week recap. \n \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \n\xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \n\xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \n\n\n View in browser
```

I tried using regex to eliminate the repeating special characters with this:

```
re.sub(r"""|b"|(\\n)+|b|\\xe2\\x80\\x8c '""", "", string.decode('utf-8'))
```

When I run this code, I get:

```
Asana Check out your two-week recap. \n \u200c \u200c
```

I can't remove the special unicode characters with regex, so tried doing

```
string.encode("ascii", "ignore")
```

That works! But, then I still have some special characters in the string:

```
b"Asana Check out your two-week recap. \n
```

But, when I try to use

```
re.sub(r"""|b"|(\\n)+|b'""", "", string)
```

I get an error that I can't use .sub on a byte object. If I add `.decode('utf-8')` the `\n` don't get replaced.

Can someone help explain what's going on and how to fix this? I'm used to just dealing with plain text strings.

Here's some code below, but I'm not sure how to create the same kind of 'byte' object that I currently have in the pandas dataframe. So, it's a simple string below:

```
string = 'b"Asana Check out your two-week recap. \n \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \n\xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \n\xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \xe2\x80\x8c \n\n\n View in browser'

string = re.sub(r"""|b"|(\\n)+|b'""", "", string.decode('utf-8'))
    string
    
    string = string.encode("ascii", "ignore")
    
    string
    re.sub(r"""|b"|\\n|b'""", "", string.decode('utf-8'))
```

Thanks and please let me know how I can make this question easier to answer!

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `string.decode('utf-8').strip()`? See https://ideone.com/XMgfae

Comment: Read [_The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excluses!)_](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) and https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: Also, see `print(" ".join(string.decode('utf-8').replace('\u200C','').strip().split()))` [result](https://ideone.com/NspEmf).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew for some reason when I use that in the panda dataframe it doesn't work. It works when I use your print statement, but not when I just try to replace the object in the pandas dataframe. I'm having difficulty coming up with replicable code because I don't know how to create this byte object that's coming from my original data (it's an mbox file that's being converted)

Comment: `df['col'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x.decode('utf-8').replace('\u200C','').strip().split()))`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x.decode('utf-8').replace('\u200C','').strip().split()))
```

*Details*:

- `x.decode('utf-8')` - decode the byte string as a UTF8 string
- `.replace('\u200C','')` - remove the zero-width joiner symbol
- `.strip()` - remove leading/trailing whitespace
- `.split()` - split with whitespace
- `" ".join(...)` - join the resulting list with  a space